# The program can't start because libiconv-2.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: postgresql, postgis, spatial

I am trying to load towns data ( from MassGIS website) as suggested at http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01.

The error that I am getting is "The program can't start because libiconv-2.dll is missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

I have searched about it a lot but couldn't get to the correct solution. I need to implement various queries on this spatial database and I have both PostgreSQL 9.4 and PostGIS 2.2.0 successfully installed in my computer.

Any suggestion / answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If libiconv-2.dll is infact missing from your computer , it will be in the PostgreSQL bin directory then just run the following command in a command prompt

```
copy libiconv.dll libiconv-2.dll
```